# Boostrap carousel show 3 images per slide truncated

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I'm trying to set up a Bootstrap 3 carousel to show 3 images per active slide, I want the next and previous images to be truncated but the centre image full width, similar to this example: https://thescene.com/.

I've played around with this for quite a while but can't seem to get the truncated effect? My initial idea is to have the containing div full width to show all 3 images in full with an overflow:hidden property to get the effect, but the carousel itself needs to be 1280px wide. Codeply is here: http://www.codeply.com/go/6eBfBskTsV

Comment: You want one image at a time...

Comment: what about using this plugin http://coolcarousels.frebsite.nl/c/2/

Comment: Thanks, it seems using an external plugin is the way to go rather than trying to customise the Bootstrap carousel

Comment: I implemented something similar: https://www.codeply.com/go/TaYM0MUl5c/bootstrap-carousel-with-next-prev-(partial)

Answer (score 0):

Why not grab one online? This component seems has a partial nearby image effect...

http://www.jssor.com/index.html

The bootstrap carousel is just a simple implementation rather than a universal solution, which means it can be cumbersome to tweak to achieve some complicated presentation. I guess unless you are just practising your skills, you won't like to make one by yourself.